# Outputting records count realtime using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working with ajax for the first time and I'm just experimenting with it for now. Eventually I want to trigger a notification on my website based on the number of records in a Mysqli table.

```
$result = $MySQLi_CON->query($sql); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
<div id="div1">
    <?php 
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    printf("there are %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
    ?>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#div1').load('backendform.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    });
}
</script>
```

This outputs the number of records in the Posts table accurately after the page has reloaded. But I want to implement ajax so that it always checks what the number is, not just after the page has reloaded. So how to I output that number real-time using ajax?

Comment: Here we go again, if you want realtime you have to use websockets. And what have you tried so far cause all I see is PHP, and not 1 attempt of using Ajax.

Comment: That's something I've looked into but I heard that websockets wasn't necessary for that. That it could be done using just ajax?

Comment: I added in the code I attempted to do that's not working. I was thinking if I refresh the div in which the number is output every 5 seconds, it'd be close to being realtime. But it's not working, just throwing errors saying the records have an undefined index.

Comment: If all you need from the database is the number of `posts` then, you could `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts` and then extract that value. It will speed up the page once you start having a lot rows in the `posts` table because that way won't pull all of the data from the database. As far your JS, seems fine except you'll keep echoing out the surrounding `<div id='div1'>` tag. Many ways to solve including just putting an `if` statement around the part that echoes the tag so that it won't always echo the tag.

Comment: What do you mean with the `if` statement in the last line?
Using the js code in the question there is no problem for when I refresh `div2` in this code. `ranint` is a random integer so I know it refreshes.

 `<div id="div2"> <script>document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = ranint;</script></div>
 <div id="div1"> <?php  $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); printf("there are %d rows.\n", $row_cnt); ?> </div>`

But when I want div1 is just throws the errors like I stated.